# Translating "I'm yours"; does あなたのもの work?

Tags: translation

> あなたのもの

I'm trying to translate the phrase "I'm yours" in a loving way. Or just "yours" as in I belong to you and vice versa.

I know a bit of Japanese but I'm a bit confused here. I know "anata no" is something belonging to "you". The "mo no" part is what confuses me.

Am I saying "your thing"?

Comment: Your sentence does not mean anything since it is not finished. It would be the same to ask how to translate "your thing".

Comment: it would be helpful if you could provide more context, but it seems like you are translating something of a romantic nature?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, (私は)あなたのもの is a common phrase, and it is used [more than a hundred times](http://www.uta-net.com/user/index_search/search2.html?frm=ichiran&textfield=%82%A0%82%C8%82%BD%82%CC%82%E0%82%CC) in lyrics. You can also use other first- and second-person pronouns, for example 僕は君のもの. Of course this can be one of the heaviest expressions to show your love, but that's up to you.

And it's best to leave it in hiragana, just as the OP suggested. The [BCCWJ corpus](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/) returns 57 results for あなたのもの and no result for あなたの者.

物【もの】 usually refers to inanimate things. 私はあなたの物 is not entirely wrong, but it may look similar to "I'm your gadget" or something. It's possible to say 私は[あなたの物じゃない](http://www.uta-net.com/song/124065/)のよ in an angry tone, though.

者【もの】 at least refers to a person, but 私はあなたの者 looks even weirder to me in this situation. A Google search for あなたの者 primarily returns several results from Christian Bibles (which are full of uncommon and archaic expressions), and they're basically used in the sense of "your follower/believer".

Answer (score 0):

私はあなたの物です。

You can also use "もの" but the kanji helps to keep things cleaner. As you have it in the original question, it just reads "your stuff."

もの does literally mean "thing/stuff," etc., but it's used in various situations. Like most Japanese words, context and sentence structure are important.

For example, you can say: おいしいものが食べたい。
Eng: "I want to eat something tasty." Then there's 食べ物 which *is* the word "food," yet breaking it down you have "edible things."

It seems you might have read the original phrase as having two particles, "mo" and "no," where it's just a single word ("mono" in Romaji).

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a more "loving" way of saying "I'm yours" than "I'm your thing". Are you sure you have the right translation there?

Comment: You sure that's the right 漢字 to use there. Wouldn't [者]{もの} be preferable?

Comment: @virmaior no it is not 者.

Comment: @oldergod I don't mean to say it should be ... I mean to say that if you're going to stick a kanji on it which would be wrong that it would be better to err with 者 than 物. (Am I still wrong in the limited sense I intended?)

Comment: Write it as a kanji is not wrong and it would be 物 and not 者.